# How to write only logs with 200 status

Tags: nginx, lua, http-status-codes

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following:

1. Request is coming in.
2. `HttpLuaModule` performs some action against the request. If request is valid than Lua will finish processing with `ngx.exit(202)`. But there are some conditions that may (and will) occur during the processing and `nginx` might return 403 , 404, 503 Errors.

What I want to do is to write to access logs only requests that have 200 Status code. 
Basically I would like to do something like this:

```
location /foo {
    content_by_lua_file "/opt/nginx/lua/process.lua";
    if (status == 200) {
        access_log "/path/to/the/access_log"
    }
```

I'm very new to both nginx and lua so for me it's a bit of a challenge to figure out where to place and if statement (ether after `content_by_lua_file` or in side lua file) and what this if statement should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with:

## auth.lua

```
-- Some logic goes here
-- ....
-- ....
ngx.var.return_status = 200
```

## nginx.conf

```
http {
   lua_package_path .....;
   lua_package_cpath ....;

   rewrite_by_lua_no_postpone on;

   server {
      
     set $return_status 1;
    
     location /foo {
        rewrite_by_lua_file "<apth_to_aut.lua";

        if ($return_status = 200) {
            access_log  <path_to_access_log>  format;
            return 200;
        }
     }
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 30):

nginx 1.7.0+ allows using an if condition in `access_log` directive itself.

```
access_log path [format [buffer=size [flush=time]] [if=condition]];

The if parameter (1.7.0) enables conditional logging.
A request will not be logged if the condition evaluates to “0” or an empty string
```

Combined with `map` directive its possible to send log events to different logs based on various conditions.

```
http {

    map $status $normal {
        ~^2  1;
        default 0;
    }
    map $status $abnormal {
        ~^2  0;
        default 1;
    }
    map $remote_addr $islocal {
        ~^127  1;
        default 0;
    }

    server {

        access_log logs/access.log combined if=$normal;
        access_log logs/access_abnormal.log combined if=$abnormal;
        access_log logs/access_local.log combined if=$islocal;

    }  
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html

Comment: This is excellent. It answers a somewhat different question I had about conditional logging.

Answer (score 4):

you can do it by using `ngx.log` and `log_by_lua` directives.

```
location /conditional_log{
        log_by_lua 'if ngx.status == 200 then ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "It is 200") end';
        content_by_lua 'ngx.say("I am ok") ngx.exit(200)';
    }
```

In the above code, we use `log_by_lua` which is called while running in log phase. In that if `ngx.status == 200`, we use ngx.log to trigger the logging using `ngx.log`.

This will write to `error_log`. Not sure how to write it to `access_log`.

For reference

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.log

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#log_by_lua

Comment: Thank you for you answer, But I really wanted to write to the access_log, I came up with a very wiered solution: set a global variable `foo` then changed `content_by_lua` to `rewrite_by_lua` and at the end if everything is OK, I change varibale `foo` to 200. Then after script I have a similar if statement that I posted in the question. Hope someone can suggest something more elegant.

Answer (score 4):

In every question is a part of answer. You were very close:

```
if ($status != "200") {
    access_log off;
}
```

Check info for version availability here.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables

Also, almost all access log format vars are available in "modern" versions:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html